# How to fail installation if WebAppPool doesn't exist?

Tags: iis, wix, application-pool

I use the following Wix code to create a WebApplication in IIS and assign it to a specific Application Pool.

```
<iis:WebAppPool Id="AppPool_Wcf" Name="$(var.WCF_APP_POOL)" />

<iis:WebSite Id="Web_site" Description="$(var.WEB_SITE_DESCRIPTION)" SiteId="[SITEID]">
    <iis:WebAddress Id="Web_Address" Port="*"/>
</iis:WebSite>

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Directory Id="SITEPATH">
        <Directory Id="WCF_VIRT_DIR" Name="$(var.WCF_VIRT_DIR)">
            <Component Id="IIS_Wcf" Guid="$(var.deploy.wcf.guid)" KeyPath="yes">
                <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="Wcf_VirtualDir" Alias="$(var.WCF_VIRT_DIR)" WebSite="Web_site" Directory="WCF_VIRT_DIR">
                    <iis:WebApplication Id="Wcf_Application" Name="$(var.WCF_VIRT_DIR)" WebAppPool="AppPool_Wcf" />
                </iis:WebVirtualDir>
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>
```

App Pool should already exist, as it’s shared with some other applications.

If it doesn’t exist, setup succeeds, assigning Web Application to a mysterious `<Invalid Application Pool>` (can be seen in web app Properties).
The application even works!

How can I make installation fail if App Pool is not found?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an immediate custom action for this. For instance, in C#/DTF it could be implemented like this:

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult FailIfAppPoolNotExist(Session session)
{
  DirectoryEntry appPool = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://localhost/w3svc/AppPools/{0}", session["APP_POOL_NAME"]));

  if (appPool == null)
  {
    return ActionResult.Failure;
  }
  return ActionResult.Success;
}
```